# Button Navigation in ECSlidingViewController

Tags: iphone, ecslidingviewcontroller

I have used ECSLidingViewController for navigation which works fine in my project. The problem i am facing is, i have four buttons on the main screen. When i navigate to other screens using these buttons the sliding menu dosent work on that screen. 
Is there a different way to navigate using button click in ECSlidingViewController.

Thanx

Comment: hi, are you using segues to navigate between views ?

Comment: i was using them.... now i have changed it since i am using ESClidingViewController......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sliding menu button will only work in root view controller, but if you pushes your view and navigate to other view, then navigation button will work for back action but PAN gesture will continue to work.

Comment: actually i was showing the views modally. I want the sliding menu to work on all the views. Is this possible? i.e no matter how i navigate to other views the sliding menu should always b there in every view.

Comment: try to call this method - (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
} when user presses back button

Comment: i want the actual buttons to navigate to their respective screens, but i also want the sliding menu to be available in those screens. I dont want any back buttons. Thank You.